# SQLite Crash on Inserting Items

Tags: c++, database, sqlite

I have three queries that I'm running through SQLite.  These are what I'm running; the first is the table declaration and then the next 3 are the actual queries.

Declaration:

> "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS items (busid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, ipaddr TEXT, time TEXT DEFAULT (NOW()));"

Queries:

> 1. (Works) "INSERT INTO items (time, ipaddr) VALUES ('test', '192.168.1.1');"
> 2. (Crashes) "INSERT INTO items (busid, ipaddr) VALUES (10, '192.168.1.1');"
> 3. (Crashes) "INSERT INTO items (ipaddr) VALUES ('192.168.1.1');"

Query 1 works fine, whereas queries 2 and 3 cause a crash by means of an EXC_BAD_ACCESS within sqlite3ExprCodeTarget.  Tracing back, I discover the last point my code touches is a sqlite3_prepare_v2() statement, which passes a valid database/string/etc. and, as I said, works fine with statement 1 above but not 2 or 3.  What's wrong with this, and how can I fix it?  Thanks.

EDIT 1:  To clarify, Query 1, 2, and 3 are run separately in different runs of the program, not in sequence, and the database is destroyed in between runs, so running Query 1 has no effect on running Query 2 after the reset.

EDIT 2:  Example C++ source file showing issue:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <sqlite3.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    sqlite3 *db;
    sqlite3_open("/Users/Justin/Desktop/test.db", &db);

    string createQuery = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS items (busid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, ipaddr TEXT, time TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT (NOW()));";
    sqlite3_stmt *createStmt;
    cout << "Creating Table Statement" << endl;
    sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, createQuery.c_str(), createQuery.size(), &createStmt, NULL);
    cout << "Stepping Table Statement" << endl;
    if (sqlite3_step(createStmt) != SQLITE_DONE) cout << "Didn't Create Table!" << endl;

    // COMMENT OUT UNUSED ONES
    // First one works, second and third ones fail.

    string insertQuery = "INSERT INTO items (time, ipaddr) VALUES ('test', '192.168.1.1');"; // WORKS!
    //string insertQuery = "INSERT INTO items (busid, ipaddr) VALUES (10, '192.168.1.1');"; // FAILS!
    //string insertQuery = "INSERT INTO items (ipaddr) VALUES ('192.168.1.1');"; // FAILS!

    sqlite3_stmt *insertStmt;
    cout << "Creating Insert Statement" << endl;
    sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, insertQuery.c_str(), insertQuery.size(), &insertStmt, NULL);
    cout << "Stepping Insert Statement" << endl;
    if (sqlite3_step(insertStmt) != SQLITE_DONE) cout << "Didn't Insert Item!" << endl;

    cout << "Success!" << endl;
}
```

Just set the database path in the source code to wherever you want it to create the test database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i downloaded your source, compiled and ran with each line uncommented in turn, all works ok

sqlite version 3.6.23.1

redhat 5 32 bit

so i guess the answer is - upgrade to latest version of sqlite

Comment: i had a v long make && sudo make install running so I wanted something to pass the time :-)

Comment: Well, I tried the latest version of sqlite (I'm on Mac OS 10.6.4 and it comes bundled with 3.6.12) and the second two don't crash but also don't add the item; it seems the error is "unknown function: NOW()".  So it seems the error is in the CREATE TABLE statement where I try to set the default value for time to NOW().  It turns out instead of `NOW()` I have to use `date('now')` in SQLite.  That was incorrect SQL (in SQLite at least) and it was causing the crash instead of a proper error.  Thanks for the help though; it turns out the new version helped debug, even though both of them run.